# PDF viewers can navigate bookmarks with keyboard

Tags: windows, pdf-viewer, bookmark, keyboard-shortcuts, menu

I need to find a PDF viewer, working on Windows, that can navigate the bookmarks by keyboard only. In specific, it should be able to do these with hotkeys only:

- Open and close bookmark panel ([PDF-XChange Viewer](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/pdf-xchange-viewer) (my favorite), Nitro and Foxit support this)
- **Navigate bookmarks** (see [How to focus on a panel of a program?](https://superuser.com/q/1280954/301042) for more detail on the problem)

Bonus point if night mode is supported. Comments and editing are not necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Sumatra](http://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/)

- Open/close bookmark panel: <kbd>F12</kbd>
- Focus/unfocus bookmark panel: <kbd>F6</kbd>
- Expand a node: <kbd>Numpad +</kbd>, <kbd>→</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+Numpad 6</kbd>
- Collapse a node: <kbd>Numpad -</kbd>, <kbd>←</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+Numpad 4</kbd>
- Expand/collapse all child nodes: <kbd>Numpad *</kbd>/<kbd>Numpad /</kbd>
- Expand/collapse all bookmarks: <kbd>Shift+Numpad *</kbd>/<kbd>Shift+Numpad /</kbd>

This isn't written in the document strangely.

Not only it support navigating bookmarks by keyboard, it also has a [command line  argument](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/docs/Command-line-arguments.html) allow you to match an entry and scroll to that destination.

If you are on laptop and numpad keys are inconvenient to you, you can use AutoHotKey to remap those shortcuts. [Here is my setup](https://forum.sumatrapdfreader.org/t/suggestions-for-bookmarks/1582/5?u=ooker).